# Ubuntu and Wine

Tags: windows, games

Can Ubuntu be used with wine to load older windows 98 games rather than using a virtual box.  I have several titles that just refuse to run with my newer hardware.  I have another machine with slower hardware and older graphics cards that I can use to do this. Or do you use a virtual box install on Linux to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/), to see if the software titles that you have will run under Wine; otherwise you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  Also check out how well VirtualBox supports various [operating systems](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) in its virtual machines.